Error Message "Run Package Manager or apt-get to
I have received the above message under a red disc with a white line on the main /home screen.  As you will see below I have tried to run apt-get but nothing works, can someone please give some guidence to a confused non-teccie?
$ apt-get autoremove
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
johngun1@johngun1-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ apt-get remove
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
johngun1@johngun1-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ apt-get autoclean
E: Could not open lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the download directory

I have rebooted several times and the same message always comes back.

One of the previous questions worked, Thank you.
